# Expiring elements inside mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

Note: First time using MongoDB.

Technology: php mongodb
Scenario:

The data is suppose to hold programs offered. Document looks like:

```
{
    LocationName: 'name of the location',
    LocationAddress: 'Main street., Popular City, PC',
    LocationManager: 'Mr. Manager',
    LocationPhone: '555 555 1212',
    Programs :
             [
                 {
                 ProgramName : 'Excellence Prgram',
                 ProgramStartDate : '12-05-2012',
                 ProgramEndDate : '3-15-2013'
                 },
                 {
                 ProgramName : 'Excellence Prgram for me',
                 ProgramStartDate : '1-05-2012',
                 ProgramEndDate : '2-15-2013'
                 },
                 {
                 ProgramName : 'Excellence Prgram for three',
                 ProgramStartDate : '1-05-2012',
                 ProgramEndDate : '4-15-2013'
                 }
             ]
}
```

Questions:

1. To query by start and end date, what would be the query on collection?
2. The programs expire by end date and new programs are added to each document frequently. Keeping expired programs in the document, I assume, at some point will become inefficient. How can expired programs be archived?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: apparently this is a tough one to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me, but I hate giving this type of answer. I would radically change how you're storing documents:

I would make a document look like this:

```
 {
     _id : 1823098123908831809
     ProgramName : 'Excellence Prgram',
     ProgramStartDate : '12-05-2012',
     ProgramEndDate : '3-15-2013'
     Location : {
         LocationName: 'name of the location',
         LocationAddress: 'Main street., Popular City, PC',
         LocationManager: 'Mr. Manager',
         LocationPhone: '555 555 1212',
 }
```

The problem you'll have now is that you can query for Locations that have an Active program, but pulling out only the programs that meet your business rules will be tricky.

With this reorg you're able to write a simple query for all documents in the collection that have dates that meet your business rules.

Locations changing details does get more complex, but this is really a minor use case. You'll query for active programs often. Locations change managers rarely.

This will also allow you to maintain history. If you only update location information for relevant runs of a program you'll have a record that the May 2013 run of Excellence Program took place at the old location on Mains street, with Mr Manager (even though it's now held on Front Street, run by Mrs. Manager).